# C programming about scanf and array

Tags: c

I try to make this program when I enter 3 5 2 5 5 5 0

=>

Enter numbers: 3 5 2 5 5 5 0

The largest number is 5

The occurrence count of the largest number is 4

```
int main()
{
  int a[10];
  int i,max, count;

  printf("Enter numbers: ");        
  for(i=0;i<10;i++)
  {
    scanf("%d",&a[i]);
  }
  max=a[0];                     

  count=1;

  for(i=1;i<10;i++)
  {
    if(max<a[i])
    {
        count = 1;
        max = a[i];
    }
    else if(max==a[i])
    {
        count++;
    }
  } 

  printf("The largest number is %d\n",max);
  printf("The occurrence count of the largest number is %d",count);

  return 0;
}
```

It is my code, but it is totally wrong..

I don't know what should I do

please help me

Comment: You're putting all your numbers in `a[10]` (which is out-of-bounds) in the `scanf`. Change it to `a[i]`.

Comment: Since this is essentially a typo, you should delete your question.

Comment: I changed a[10]to a[i], but compiler shows wrong

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "compiler shows wrong"? You need to add `#include <stdio.h>`; apart from that, your code compiles without error.

Answer (score 2):

You've got several errors.

1. In your first loop, you want to read into `a[i]`, not `a[10]`.
2. Your code corrently assumes you always type in 10 numbers.  It looks like you wanted a value of 0 to end the list.  Me, I'd use end-of-file to end the list.  To check for `0` you need an extra line `if(a[i] == 0) break;` in the loop.  To check for EOF (or other non-numeric input which will cause problems) you could check to see that `scanf` returns 1.
3. In case you enter less than 10 numbers, you'll need a new variable that knows how many variables you actually entered.  I set `nn = i` after the first loop.
4. Then you just need to change the second loop to run from `1` to `nn`, not `10`.

Putting this all together, we have:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  int a[10];
  int i,max, count, nn;

  printf("Enter numbers: ");        
  for(i=0;i<10;i++)
  {
    if(scanf("%d",&a[i]) != 1) break;
    if(a[i] == 0) break;
  }
  nn = i;
  max=a[0];                     
  count=1;
  for(i=1;i<nn;i++)
  {
    if(max<a[i])
    {
        count = 1;
        max = a[i];
    }
    else if(max==a[i])
    {
        count++;
    }
  } 

  printf("The largest number is %d\n",max);
  printf("The occurrence count of the largest number is %d\n",count);

  return 0;
}
```

This seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

Code is OK other than the user needs to enter 10 numbers.

There is no need to store previous numbers, so code can simply examine each new number until `'\n'` is encountered.   Just keep look for the end-of-line before looking for the number.

```
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(void) {
  int count = 0;
  int max = INT_MIN;
  printf("Enter numbers: ");
  for (;;) {
    int ch;
    int num;
    while (isspace(ch = fgetc(stdin)) && ch != '\n') {
      ;
    }
    if (ch == '\n' || ch == EOF) break;
    ungetc(ch, stdin);
    if (scanf("%d", &num) != 1) break;
    if (num >= max) {
      count++;
      if (num > max) {
        max = num;
        count = 1;
      }
    }
  }
  printf("The largest number is %d\n", max);
  printf("The occurrence count of the largest number is %d", count);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Now wiki, amend anything else it may need.